# Performance with Strings in a VB Application

Tags: vb.net

In my VB application,I am copying huge amount of data using VB string?
This results in performance issue.
What shoul I use in place of VB string to improve performance?

Answer (score 2):

Try to make sure you are always passing ByRef wherever possible (in VB6). In VB.Net this is not an issue. Also, maybe preallocate your strings. Analysis and a better description of your programming task can help provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This two part article](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html) is good source of information for VB6. Some tips mentioned there are:

- Use $ version of string functions (i.e. Replace$ instead of Replace).
- Use LenB() to check if string is empty (or not).
- Use vbNullString constant instead of "".

Comment: Thanks,I already implemented this

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to pre-allocate a byte/char array that is big enough to hold all your concatenated strings.

If you are using VB.NET, then there is the `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 0):

With VB 6 maybe [this](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=155206) can help you out.

Taken out from the page:

> The cStringBuilder class takes a different approach. When you initialize the 
>   class, it pre-allocates a 1MB buffer of memory to store the string in,
>   so the string can grow and shrink dynamically within that 1MB space
>   and never need to reallocate any memory. The only time it needs to
>   reallocate is when the string grows bigger than the currently
>   allocated buffer. When the string buffer grows, it is always in
>   increments of 1MB.
>
> How Do I Use It? Here is a run-down of all the functions and
>   properties available in cStringBuilder:
>
> Property StringData As String Gets or sets the data stored in the
>   StringBuilder.
>
> Property Length As Long Gets the length of the data stored in the
>   StringBuilder.
>
> Sub Clear Resets the stored string to nothing, and resizes the
>   in-memory buffer back to 1MB.
>
> Sub Append(str As String) Adds the string str on to the end of the
>   data stored in the cStringBuilder.
>
> Sub Insert(index As Long, str As String) Inserts a string (str) into
>   the StringBuilder at a specific index (index). Note that the index is
>   zero-based, so to insert to the beginning of the string, specify 0 as
>   the index.
>
> Sub Overwrite(index As Long, str As String) Inserts a string (str)
>   into the StringBuilder at a specific index (index), overwriting the
>   data at that point, rather than moving it to the right as is the case
>   with Insert. If the data you insert goes past the end of the stored
>   data, the excess will be appended normally.
>
> Sub Remove(index As Long, length As Long) Removes a section (length
>   characters) of the stored string, starting at index. If length = 0,
>   the entire string starting at index is removed.

And the usage is also quite easy

```
'Extremely short example:
Dim sb As New cStringBuilder

sb.StringData = "Hello, "
sb.Append "Wxld!"
sb.Insert 8, "o"
sb.Overwrite 9, "r"

MsgBox sb.StringData
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10270434)

Comment: Agree to that, post is 6 years old... Back in these days links were totally fine

Comment: Well the simple fix is to edit the question and include the relevant quote from the link and therefore it is no longer a link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a StringBuilder from .NET? It is marked as "COM Visible", which means you should be able to use it from VB 6.